How do I fix the Java Timeout Error using java.util.Scanner?
I am trying to include user input in my code, but I keep getting the same error: "Error: Command failed: timeout 7 java Main.java".
I have tried using a variety of online IDEs. They all give this error. Is there one that I could use that won't give this error?
Here is my code:
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What is your name?");
    String name = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Hello " + name);
  }
}


Are you executing your program on an online IDE / compiler website? If so, the website might be getting confused as to why your program is taking so long (since it's waiting for input), and it's terminating your program early, assuming it crashed. If this code was executed locally, it'd work fine.

How exactly are you running the program? The code works normally for me.

Your code works for me. Whatever is causing that Error, it is NOT something in your code.

Does it have to be an online IDE?

Some online IDEs allow you to specify input before you run the program. Look for a button that does that.

Yes, it does have to be online. Also, the contest of my problem doesn't allow for inputting before.

@EverettHolbrook write a method that accepts all the inputs and write a unit test for it. The input CLI/REPL stuff is not really part of the business logic. It can be abstracted away. Learn to separate concerns. There is no problem with installing the JDK locally and using a proper IDE. Run the code locally, then submit it.

@Mr.Polywhirl we have to respect an answer that it has to be an online IDE as this could be for a number of reasons, for example: (1) the asker is using a school computer and not allowed to install anything; (2) the asker is learning computer science and is using Java today, but will stop using it next week and start using C++ or Rust instead, so there's no point in installing something just for a week's use.

Online Java compilers are not fully featured IDEs, and have limited features. Most of them do not offer interactive input. For example, https://onecompiler.com/java times out after 7 seconds while trying to read non-existent input (hence the message you are seeing).
One online compiler that does offer interactive input is https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler. You will need to tick the "Interactive" check box on the right. Then your application will run as you expect.
This is just the status quo; you can't rely on the existence of such features online as they may change in future. On the other hand, if you could install a Java Development Kit and an IDE on your local machine, you'll find them more reliable.
